# MIDI out from freeware sequencer to PD or Max/MSP

Tags: audio

I'm looking for a way to send MIDI from a cheap or free MIDI sequencer to Pure Data or Max MSP so I can do realtime MIDI processing in PD/MAX. So I guess I have a couple questions:

- What is a good cheap/free midi sequencer (that runs in Windows 7) that supports MIDI out to another program
- How do I configure MIDI out?

Is this something normal midi sequencers can do? It seems like it should be pretty basic, but I was having trouble finding information on it.

Comment: What OS are you on? PD runs everywhere, but MIDI seqs tend to be platform specific

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up, the problem I was having was that I had no virtual MIDI driver installed, so nothing was showing up as available for MIDI input/output. I fixed this problem by downloading and installing [LoopBe1](http://www.nerds.de/en/loopbe1.html) which is free for personal use. Thanks for the help!

Comment: i'm surprised Midi Ox / Midi Yoke would not do the same thing, but good to know about LoopBe1!

Answer (score 1):

Max/MSP has the midiparse object which is incredibly useful for handling midi data. Midi Ox is a program that will help you with routing occasionally. As far as freeware, you get what you pay for. Hydrogen is an open source a drum machine that will send midi out. You'll just to configure Max or Pd to receive the channel you're sending out of your sequencer.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll try it out and see how it goes.